# Why are the Lp vector norms continuous over the nonnegative reals but not over the reals unless p is an even (positive) integer.

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

I am reading the textbook *Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics*,in page 147 it says:"the Lp vector norms in equation (2.11) are continuous over the nonnegative reals but not over the reals unless p is an even (positive) integer." (2.11) is the definition of the Lp norm,but I just can't figure out why? can someone explain it and give a point(negative) in domain which is not continuous with a odd *p*?

Comment: What do they mean by this? A vector norm is a function $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}.$ Do they mean continuous over the set of vectors with nonnegative real entries?

Comment: In my opinion,continuous over nonegative reals is exactly what you said,and not continuous over reals means not continous over a set of vectors with reals( can be positive ,negative or zero).And in the book,it also says "A function of a vector or a matrix is continuous if it is continuous for each element of the vector or matrix."

Comment: The textbook sentence is just plain wrong. The $\ell_p$-norm is a continuous function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.